# Boost Libraries Support for MS VC++ 10.0

Tags: c++, boost

Friends

I have been using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express edition and also downloaded the Boost Libraries for Windows and I would want to have Boost linked with VC++ so that I can run programs that involves Boost libraries in VC++.
Please provide some inputs on Boost with VC++

Thank you

Comment: What is the actual question? It should simply work. What exactly do you need to know? (And by the way, thee is no VC++ 2010 Express yet. There is a 2008 Express, and a VS2010 Beta (which is not the Express edition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have download and extract the whole library to a folder, c:\boost.

1. open the visual studio 2010 commandline window from the Start Menu, so that all VS2010 environments are pre-set for you.
2. navigate to c:\boost
3. Run bjam.exe,  and wait.
   Alternatively, you can save the following 3 lines into a a file build.bat(as I do)

   bjam.exe link=static runtime-link=static threading=multi --layout=versioned stage

   bjam.exe link=static runtime-link=shared threading=multi --layout=versioned stage

   bjam.exe link=shared runtime-link=shared threading=multi --layout=versioned stage
   and run build.bat, after the build, all libs are in .\stage

Answer (score 3):

Just follow these instructions [Getting Started on Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)

Answer (score 1):

just a note, the latest trunk of boost is not building on 2010 yet.